# Find the third eigen vector.

Tags: matrices

If two eigen vectors of a symmetric matrix are  $\left ( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-1 \\
1 \end{array} \right)$ and $\left ( \begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \end{array} \right)$ then the third eigen vector is ?

I am aware that the eigen vectors of symmetric matrices are mutually orthogonal. How do I use this fact to find the third eigen vector?

Comment: Can you find a vector which is orthogonal with both your vectors?

Comment: @iiivooo Got it. Cross product is the key. Thanks !!

Comment: You are welcome, please consider accepting one of the answers bellow so the question is marked answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of two vectors gives a third vector which is perpendicular to both of them.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above, the cross product gives a formula and an immediate answer. However, if you're not familiar with the cross product, and as you've already hinted for the answer in your question, you can do it directly from the orthogonality condition.

Let $(a,b,c)$ be the vector, then the orthogonality reads

$$(a,b,c)\cdot (1,-1,1)=0\Leftrightarrow a-b+c=0,$$ 
$$(a,b,c)\cdot (1,0,-1)=0\Leftrightarrow a-c=0.$$

So $c=a$, and $b =2a$. We are free to choose any nonzero $a$, and letting $a=1$, we  obtain $(1,2,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If we have a matrix, $A$, and we have $Av_1=\lambda_1v_1$ and $Av_2=\lambda_2v_2$, then $\langle v_1, v_2\rangle=\langle \lambda_1^{-1}Av_1, v_2\rangle=\langle \lambda_1^{-1}v_1, Av_2\rangle=\lambda_1^{-1}\lambda_2\langle v_1, v_2\rangle$, so that eigenvalues with distinct Eigen values are orthogonal. Now if we assume that all of the Eigen values are distinct, we have that the Eigen vector must lie in $\{v\in\mathbb{R}^3|v*(1, 0, -1)=0, v*(1, -1, 1)\}=\mathbb{R}(1, 2, 1)$. The cases where the Eigenvalues are the same is solved similarly.